# swings trouble with splash screen

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

I am trying to implement splash screen followed my main activity. Code below is what I have manged to do so far. And I am not able to get my splash screen working. Please help.
On running the the file its showing SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returned null.What to do ?

SplashDemo.java

```
public class SplashDemo extends Frame implements ActionListener {
    static void renderSplashFrame(Graphics2D g, int frame) {
        final String[] comps = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Clear);
        g.fillRect(120,140,200,40);
        g.setPaintMode();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("Loading "+comps[(frame/5)%3]+"...", 120, 150);
    }
    public SplashDemo() {
        super("SplashScreen demo");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Menu m1 = new Menu("File");
        MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem("Exit");
        m1.add(mi1);
        mi1.addActionListener(this);
        this.addWindowListener(closeWindow);

        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
        setMenuBar(mb);
        mb.add(m1);
        final SplashScreen splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
        if (splash == null) {
            System.out.println("SplashScreen.getSplashScreen() returned null");
            return;
        }
        Graphics2D g = splash.createGraphics();
        if (g == null) {
            System.out.println("g is null");
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            renderSplashFrame(g, i);
            splash.update();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(90);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        splash.close();
        setVisible(true);
        toFront();
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static WindowListener closeWindow = new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
            e.getWindow().dispose();
        }
    };

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        SplashDemo test = new SplashDemo();
    }
}
```

Comment: How is SplashScreen implemented?

Comment: how it will have to be implemented ? I want to add a image but don't to how . Can you please help

Comment: Since you can call it I guess that you have written some parts of it, can you add it to the question? It is quite hard to write it from scratch when you already have some parts of it

Comment: You should probably put renderSplashFrame in your splashscreen class

Comment: See [SplashScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) with some possibilites. By the way, all that is old **awt**, not the newer **swing** GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your splash screen image, say MySplashyScreen.gif, and put it in a directory called images (or wherever you like).

Then on startup use this command line:

java -splash:images/MySplashyScreen.gif SplashDemo